# Output Buffer versus file_get_contents in PHP

Tags: php, templates, file-get-contents, output-buffering

What are the differences between these two ways of obtaining file contents? Which one is better and more efficient? I think they both obtain the same results but I really don't know which method is better.

For example.

**This code uses output buffering to obtain the file's content:**

```
ob_start();
include('foo/bar.tpl');
$output .= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

**This code uses file_get_contents and gets the same results.**

```
$output = file_get_contents('foo/bar.tpl');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the second example will just output the file content as **raw text**, while in the first the file content will be parsed by the `PHP interpreter`, meaning if some `PHP` code exists within it, it will be executed!